# Overlapping TextView items in RelativeLayout in 2.2; no problem in 1.6

Tags: android, overlap, android-relativelayout

I have a problem with a `RelativeLayout` containing two `TextView`s and a `ImageView`, that I use for displaying items in a `ListView`. The items are correctly displayed on Android 1.6, but on Android 2.2 the `TextView`s are overlapping.

Here is an image that shows the correct and incorrect behavior side-by-side:

[image]

And here is the source code of my RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondLine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"

    android:layout_below="@+id/firstLine"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstLine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"

    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot,

Philipp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is basically the same answer as Octavian's, but I don't think he actually explained it very well.

You have contradicting statements in your XML file.  You have:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

in both of your text views.  You also have:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/firstLine"
```

in one of the textviews.  Essentially, your trying to align to the bottom of a relative layout and then trying to put something under it.  There isn't anything "under the bottom."

Remove this contradicting logic and it should solve your problem.

Comment: I managed to solve it with Octavian's answer. Thank you for your extensive explanation!

Comment: It won't solve the problem as it just doesn't work that way. `layout_below` is going to be ignored when when you define your Views like above.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure if it is the problem but on your `TextView` with the ID `firstLine` it seems like you are aligning it to it's parents bottom like you do with `TextView` ID `secondLine`. I'm quite sure you wanted to say `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` instead.

I can't tell why it is working on Android 1.6 but not on 2.2.

Comment: You nailed it, thanks a lot! I did not notice the error. Using android:layout_alignParentTop="true" instead of android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" did the trick.